# Horizontally align two select boxes with copy inbetween

Tags: html, css, select, input

I am trying to create a "Start Time" to "Stop Time" with the times being select boxes (drop-down input).

I could use a clunky table but am looking for help to accomplish this using CSS.

Below is my HTML:

```
<p>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap res-to-time">
<select name="start" class="res_times">
<option time="start">Start Time</option>
<option time="1:00">1:00</option>
<option time="2:00">2:00</option>
</select>
</span>
</p>
<p>to</p>
<p>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap res-finish-time">
<select name="start" class="res_times">
<option time="start">Start Time</option>
<option time="1:00">1:00</option>
<option time="2:00">2:00</option>
</select>
</span>
</p>
```

I tried to float the select boxes but then the copy got jacked up and pushed one box down. Any thoughts on this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: What's your CSS? [This is all we have](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/aLtu2/) so far. What's the issue exactly, can you try to clarify a bit more?

Comment: Actually I may have been over thinking it. I assumed the copy would break onto a new line. Based on your example that is not the case. This is what I get for not just trying the obvious.

Comment: can you give your css code.i cant to find problems in html only, demo:http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/d2VJT/

Comment: Please see the updated html code above. Wordpress is adding the form to the page and I had not noticed all the extra markup. The css I added was to float the inputs styled with res_times